# Have been eating something that was/is unhealthy

Tags: past-tense, sequence-of-tenses

Should the following sentence use a present tense or past tense verb given the condition still exists?

> I have been eating something that was/is unhealthy.

Since "have been" is a past perfect tense, I feel like it's appropriate to use "was" but then again the conditions still exist.

Comment: Native speakers often / usually "backshift" in contexts like this (since ***have been eating*** refers to ***past*** activity, we tend to "echo" this with ***was** unhealthy*). It's much the same as *He said his name **was** Smith* (usually, it still ***is***, but we don't often say that).

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate word is "is" if the thing is currently unhealthy. It's only the act of eating that occurred in the past, and that's what the "have been" applies to.

The sentence

> I have been eating something that was unhealthy.

implies that the "something" you used to eat is no longer unhealthy, which has a different meaning.

Comment: I would get round the problem by just saying 'something unhealthy' - unless the food was unhealthy because that particular portion had gone off, which presumably isn't what you mean.